# Scala inheritance default parameter in parent class

Tags: scala, inheritance, default-parameters

I have an abstract class with a default value for its parameter.
I don't want to have to reuse the default value in the constructor of all the possible implementations.

```
abstract class Place(val place: String = "World")
class Message(val message: String = "Hello", p: String) extends Place(p) {
    override def toString = s"$message $place"
}
```

What I want to get

```
new Message("Hi", "Universe") = "Hi Universe" // Ok
new Message("Hi") = "Hi World" // Doesn't work, second parameter is required
new Message() = "Hello World" // Doesn't work, second parameter is required
```

I considered using an auxiliary constructor omitting the second parameter, but it doesn't help since you can't call super constructors outside of the main constructor.

I want to know how to do it, or why it is not possible. I'm not looking for a workaround, like not using inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the default value in a more elegant way:

```
object Place {
  val defaultPlace = "World"
}
abstract class Place(val place: String = Place.defaultPlace)
class Message(val message: String = "Hello", p: String = Place.defaultPlace) extends Place(p) {
  override def toString = s"$message $place"
}
```

Comment: works. not as encapsulated. Here you have 3 objects to juggle (object, abstract, and class). In particular not giving credit for object and abstract having same name. class Message has to know about object Place so using this requires more wiring, if that makes any sense. the abstract and concrete should handle it all.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that is not possible. Quite simply, you ARE passing a value to Place constructor, so it wont use the default, whatever its value might be. If you don't mind having a var instead of a val, here is a variant that works for your 3 cases:

```
abstract class Place(var place: String = "World")
class Message(val message: String = "Hello") extends Place()
{
   def this(message: String, place: String) = {
      this(message)
      this.place = place
   }
   override def toString = s"$message $place"
}
```

Constructors in Scala are a little of a mess IMHO. Sometimes a better answer is just to use factory `apply()` methods on a companion object, which are more flexible.